# onResume() is not called in SherlockFragment of SherlockFragmentActivity in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am working in an application in which I have used the Sherlock Fragment API.

I am having 6 **SherlockFragments** for making 6 different screens. Now when my application is launched, initially the onResume for all the fragments are called at once.

I am in a need of a method like in activity we use onResume for moving from one Fragment to another Fragment. I have to call a web service method when I move from one fragment to another fragment.

I tried to use the **onResume** here, but when I move from 1st to 2nd fragment, then the onResume of the 3rd fragment is called. Alternate fragment is called when we move from one fragment to then next.

Please suggest me, which method should I use to call my web service when I move from 1 fragment to next fragment.

**EDITED**: 
My actual requirement is to have an event which is called when we a Fragment is visible to user. At that event I have to call service for getting updated data.

Answer (score 0):

The `onResume` method is tied to the `Activity`. If you're moving back and forth between `Fragments` attached to a common `Activity`, `onResume` won't be called again. However, if you were to press back or navigate away from this `Activity` and then come back, `onResume` would be called.

You might consider `onAttach`.

Comment: onAttach() method is called once when the fragment is attached with its activity.

Comment: Yes. And again if it is re-attached having been detached (onDetach). I don't know your setting at all, but you might be using a ViewPager. If you're swiping between several fragments, onAttach and onDetach will be called alternately multiple times but onResume only once.

Comment: I am also facing same problem. When I swipe or move the tabs between several SherlockFragments in that case I have to call method for fetch update data from local database but my onResume() is not calling when fragment visible.

Comment: @hharry I don't know either of your situations fully, but you could also try overriding `onViewCreated`. There's no method like `onVisible`. You can check if the fragment is visible by calling `isVisible()`, but that's another matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way for fix this issue. Actually I was also facing same problem in my application. I  was using FragmentPagerAdapter for show multiple tab in ViewPager. I have just hide and show fragment on TabSelection with notifyDataChanged() method for refresh adapter.

My code:

```
/** Creating an instance of FragmentPagerAdapter */
final MyFragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);

/** Setting the FragmentPagerAdapter object to the viewPager object */
_mPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);
_mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

/** Defining tab listener */
ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            ft.hide(fragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(tab.getPosition()));
            fragmentPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            _mPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);
        }

        @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            _mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        ft.show(fragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(tab.getPosition()));
            fragmentPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            _mPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }
};
```

Comment: I am suffering from same problem bt this code is not working for me.@hharry: Have you made any change apart from this?

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me.
I've used `onStart()` rather than using `onresume()` in `sherlockfragmentactivity`.
And I called to the `notifyondatasetchanged`.